# Using Camel-hdfs in a karaf bundle

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-camel, hdfs, apache-karaf

I am trying to implement an camel route to send files in a HDFS server with an OSGI bundle, using java language with no blue print, but i can't make it work due tu hdfs scheme not being found while creating the route.

The code of the class has been tested as a Jar and works. The issue is in karaf, which seems to not be able to use camel-hdfs for the bundle, even if the camel-hdfs bundle is shown using the list command.

Here's the pom file of the project :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>the.group</groupId>
<artifactId>receiveFile</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>receiveFile</name>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi_R4_core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>activation</Export-Package>
                    <Private-Package>activation</Private-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>activation.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried also Embed-Dependency with the transitive option, but it still doesn't work and i'm kind of stuck right now.

Karaf prints the following error :

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in activation.Activator.start() of bundle group.receiveFile.
```

The log :

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in activation.Activator.start() of bundle group.receiveFile.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)[osgi-3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)[osgi-3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)[osgi-3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)[osgi-3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1244)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1216)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1205)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:500)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:291)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.4]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1027 at: >>> To[hdfs://hadoopServer/received] <<< in route: Route[[From[file://toSend/]] -> [To[hdfs://hadoopServer/rece... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: hdfs://hadoopServer/received due to: No component found with scheme: hdfs
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:879)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:172)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:722)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1789)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1575)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1444)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1412)
    at activation.Activator.start(Activator.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)[osgi-3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar:]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_11]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)[osgi-3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar:]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: hdfs://hadoopServer/received due to: No component found with scheme: hdfs
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:485)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:50)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:108)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:114)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:55)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:461)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:876)
    ... 19 more
```

- Karaf version : 2.2.8
- Maven : m2e plugin, 3.0.4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a blueprint XML file to bootstrap your application. Just to setup a < camelContext >.

Otherwise you would have to do a lot of manual osgi setup and whatnot in your activator to properly setup Camel for OSGi. All that is taken care of when using camel-blueprint.

If you still want to do it from an Activator, then check out camel-core-osgi and see what we do there.

Comment: I tried an XML route and it worked, so I guess I'll go with this. Thanks for the answer !